# Simplify limit with natural log as x approaches infinity of an exponential fraction

Tags: limits

Is this allowed?$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2^{x+17}}{2^{x}} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(x+17)\ln(2)}{x\ln(2)}$$

Comment: The equation you have written is incorrect. How did you get the logs there? Can you explain your chain of thoughts so that the flaw in your argument can be understood / explained properly.

Comment: I was hoping to use L'Hopital's rule and take derivative but for some reason I thought I remembered learning that you can use ln to bring down the exponent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that is not allowed.

Hint for the question:

Notice that $$a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$$

You can evaluate the two limit and see that they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

If it had said $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(2^{x+17})}{\log(2^x)}$ then you could say it's $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+17)\log 2}{x\log 2}.$

But $2^{x+17}$ is not the same as $\log(2^{x+17}).$

And there is a trivial way to simplify the fraction $\dfrac{2^{x+17}}{2^x}.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^x2^{17}}{2^x}=2^{17}$$